# How to sort bars in a bar plot in ascending order

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I created a bar plot using `matplotlib.pyplot` and seaborn libraries. How can I sort bars in increasing order according to `Speed`? I want to see the bars with the lowest speed on the left and the highest speed on the right.

```
df =
    Id         Speed
    1          30
    1          35 
    1          31
    2          20
    2          25
    3          80
```

My code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

%matplotlib inline

result = df.groupby(["Id"])['Speed'].aggregate(np.median).reset_index()

norm = plt.Normalize(df["Speed"].values.min(), df["Speed"].values.max())
colors = plt.cm.Reds(norm(df["Speed"])) 

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.barplot(x="Id", y="Speed", data=result, palette=colors)
plt.ylabel('Speed', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Id', fontsize=12)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['Id']).median().sort_values("Speed").plot.bar()
```

Sort the dataframe with `.sort_values("Speed")` or `.sort_values('Speed', ascending=False)` after aggregating.

EDIT:
so you need to do this:

```
result = a.groupby(["Id"])['Speed'].median().reset_index().sort_values('Speed')
```

and in sns.barplot add order:

```
sns.barplot(x='Id', y="Speed", data=a, palette=colors, order=result['Id'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to do the sorting on the `result` Series and pass its index as the order.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# aggregate data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 'Speed': [30, 35, 31, 20, 25, 80]})
result = df.groupby('Id')['Speed'].median()

# plot a bar-plot where bars are ordered by median speed
ax = sns.barplot(x=result.index, y=result, order=result.sort_values().index);
```

[image: img]