# Pandas Plot: Order bars by count column in descending order

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart

This question comes up somewhat often, but I cannot find an example where anyone is trying to plot a dataframe that has just a list of categories, **and a count** as follows:

```
df4 = df3.groupby(["Case Comments"]).agg({'Case Comments':['count']})
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Output Dataframe]

Now when I go to plot it

```
fig1 =df4.plot(kind='barh', legend=None,  ylabel='Case Count',  xlabel='Case Comments')
```

The bars are not in any kind of order, I'd like have the horizontal bars in descending order, with the highest count first.
But there's a few issues, I cannot sort on a the column created in the aggregate function, it throws a keyerror:

```
df4.sort_values('count', ascending=False)
```

I tried renaming the column, but what I tried also threw an error (I don't recall what, I removed that line of code afterward).
I looked into adding an index and referring to that in the .agg but that wasn't helpful (I tried the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44886251/4613037 and got an error).

So, having a count column is causing issues and I am not sure how to get around it, rename the column correctly or refer to it another way *to then be able to sort that column*.

End goal here is to have a sorted dataframe or horizontal bar plot so the **count is in descending order** and I can make a plot like this:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort bars in a bar plot in ascending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885933/how-to-sort-bars-in-a-bar-plot-in-ascending-order)

Comment: @Irfanuddin, I have tried that but it gives an error.  ValueError: 'Case Comments' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous. (hence why I looked into indexes).

Comment: You have two indices with same name. If you can rename one of it, it should work.